# How to apply validation to duplicate dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have drop-down box in loop. so I want to apply validation.

My Code is-

```
<select name="travelclasscmb[]" id="travelclasscmb">
<option   value="">select</option>
   <option   value="1">Car</option>
</select>



<select name="travelclasscmb[]" id="travelclasscmb">
<option   value="">select</option>
   <option   value="2">Train</option>
</select>
```

Comment: id of an element must be **unique**, all your select elements have the same id

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select ').change(function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        alert('select a value');
    }
});
```

---

ID must be unique use classes instead .

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

---

Using jQuery Validator

```
$.validator.addMethod('notNone', function (value, element) {
    return (value !== '');
}, 'Please select an option');
```

Comment: @user2932185 add class instead of `id` in loop.

Comment: i have try this but it fetching first drop-down only

Comment: $('#Savealltrvldetonsingle').click(function() {
   var travelclasscmbval=$('.travelclasscmb').val();
       if (travelclasscmbval === '') {
           alert('select a value');
       }

Comment: @user2932185 Try `$('select').change(function () {
    var travelclasscmbval = this.value;
    if (travelclasscmbval === '') {
        alert('select a value');
    }
});`

Comment: Its on change event. I want to apply on button click event. so I have change it. then it run but getting only first drop-down value from loop. I want to get all drop-down value.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, you can't have duplicate id's. Use a class instead.

For the validation you can use the `required` attribute:

```
<select name="travelclasscmb[]" class="travelclasscmb" required>
<option   value="">select</option>
   <option   value="1">Car</option>
</select>



<select name="travelclasscmb[]" class="travelclasscmb" required>
<option   value="">select</option>
   <option   value="2">Train</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use class for multiple select validation

```
<select name="travelclasscmb[]" class="travelclasscmb" required>
<option   value="">select</option>
   <option   value="1">Car</option>
</select>
<select name="travelclasscmb[]" class="travelclasscmb" required>
<option   value="">select</option>
   <option   value="2">Train</option>
</select>
**Jquery:**
$('.travelclasscmb').change(function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        alert('select a value');
    }
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/kapil_dev/mdBtz/

Comment: Why would you have a required attribute AND a jQuery validation? It's  not really a nice user experience you are creating here.

Comment: I am adding travel details. And Travel depend on selection from database. so I am putting travel type then showing travel class in while loop(fetching from database).